# Creating a report from Sharepoint data in Powerpoint

Tags: 2007

Good Morning,

I am currently looking at the projects for our area, and we are using the normal projects list on sharepoint 2007.  I have to provide a report on the progress of these projects on a weekly basis and would like to do it in a powerpoint format, or if someone can help me put it in a nice format in excel I will appreciate.

I do not have Sharepoint Server and am not allowed to download Sharepoint Designer.

Please can you assist?